# Writing and reading preferences from cfg in Python

Tags: python, config

I am new to Python, I have read the docs on how to read and write to cfg file to store and retrieve user Application preferences. However, how do I avoid the crash when the key/value isn't in the cfg file yet?

e.g. Assume I have added a new checkbox to my application, and I am trying to read it on the next launch like below but I get the error: ConfigParser.NoOptionError: No option 'check_box' in section: 'Preferences'...

```
def initUserPrefs(self):
    if len(Example.config.read('myApp.cfg')):
       if(Example.config.getboolean('Preferences', 'perform_work') == 'true'):
           self.checkbox.select() 

def writeUserPrefs(self,key,value):
    Example.config.set('Preferences', key, value)
    with open('myApp.cfg', 'wb') as configfile:
        Example.config.write(configfile)    

def onCheckBoxClicked(self):
    self.writeUserPrefs(Example.CHECK_BOX_KEY, self.checkbox.get())
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply try to catch the error using a try block.
Refer to [this page](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/errors.html) about error handling.

Comment: Is this the right way of handling reading cfg, I would have thought it would allow to create the entry if not there and maybe provide it with a default value, well at least in C++ it does...